# Using perl system() query with spaces in path variable

Tags: bash, perl

I seem to be stuck here. I want to send a system request from my script to another server via SSH, checking if a folder there exists. A folder path is passed from another script, stored in a variable and might have a space character in it. Since I couldn't replace the space with another character,  to avoid a "not found" on folder like "foo bar", I need to pass something like
 `ls '/folderpath/foo bar'` to other server's shell. 
Sample code looks like this:

```
$cmd = 'ssh -i id_pub $ssh_addr ls $remote_dir'; 
if (system($cmd) == 0) {
do something
}
```

I've exhausted all possible options - tired to escape the possible space with \ before passing it to the command, tried to pass it with ' ', " ", inside and adding both before passing it into $cmd. 
But I always end up with something like this:

```
ls \folderpath\foo\\ bar or ls \' \folderpath\foo bar\'
```

but not `ls '\folderpath\foo bar'`

I'm not that good with Perl, possible someone more experienced can recommend a workaround?

Comment: The safer thing to do is to export your variables in the environment, and not to expand them into the text parsed as shell code at all. (That's "safer" in the "security-vulnerability-avoidance" sense).

Comment: ...though `ssh` parses everything as remote code regardless, so you can't avoid needing to trust your `remote_dir` value if you aren't giving it an extra layer of shell-safe escaping (only one layer for the remote system needed if you stop using `system()` and invoke ssh with an explicit argv, but right now, you need to escape against both local and remote shells).

Comment: Consider using [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) to quote the list `["ls", $remote_dir]` into a single shell-safe string, and running `system("ssh", "-i", "id_pub", $ssh_addr, $safely_quoted_string)`.

Comment: String::ShellQuote is not in Perl by default, so, unfortunately, it wouldn't work for me(

Comment: @Igor Why not? If it's just a deployment issue and you want to run this script on hosts you can't install modules on, just copy/paste the subroutine from String::ShellQuote into your script.

Comment: ... In fact, you can automate the paste-module-code-into-script step with https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker.

Comment: In short, I strongly recommend to figure out a way to use modules, instead of figuring out where to put slashes and quotes and whatnot.  You can install the module as a user (if that's how your code runs), or just copy-paste the code for the whole module into a file and you have your own module then, or use the linked app (thanks @melpomene)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK you have several possibilities for shell expansion with the way you are doing this.

Firstly is using system() with a string. This will break all your paths on the space characters. you can solve this by using system as a list

```
system('ssh', '-i', 'id_pub', $ssh_addr, 'ls', $remote_dir)
```

Now we still have a problem as ssh will run the remote code on the remote server in a shell with shell expansion which will break the path on spaces *again*

So you need to put $remote_dir inside `'` characters to stop the remote shell from breaking up the path: giving

```
system('ssh', '-i', 'id_pub', $ssh_addr, 'ls', "'$remote_dir'")
```

Hope this helps/works

Note that as the commenters below have said this makes the assumption that  $remote_dir has no `'` characters in it. You need to be either escaping or parsing $remote_dir to ensure that you don't get a path that looks like `/file.txt'; rm -rf / #` which will attempt to remove every file on the remote  system

Comment: It's generally safer and easier to give `ssh` a pre-quoted string as a single argument than to let it piece together the string itself. `system('ssh', '-i', 'id_pub', $ssh_addr, "ls $remotedir")`. This requires the value of `remotedir` itself to be appropriately escaped, rather than trying to wrap it in quotes. (For example, both `system(..., 'ls', "'$remote_dir'")` and `system(..., "ls '$remotedir'")` will fail if `$remotedir` contains a single quote.)

Comment: Injecting literal single quotes is only safe if you trust your `remote_dir` not to contain literal single quotes itself. They're legal in filenames, so that's not a wise thing to trust.

Comment: String::ShellQuote is the proper way to quote an argument for a bourne-compatible shell as @ikegami's answer notes.

Answer (score 5):

Running a local shell and using it to escape your command to be safe for the remote shell would look like this:

```
system('env', "ssh_addr=$ssh_addr", "remote_dir=$remote_dir", 'bash', '-c',
       'printf -v remote_cmd "%q " ls -- "$remote_dir"; ssh "$ssh_addr" "$remote_cmd"');
```

Unlike just using `"'$remote_cmd'"`, the above works with all possible values, including intentionally malicious ones, so long as your remote shell is also bash.

<sub>Thanks to [@ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54831828/14122) for demonstrating the use of the end-of-options sigil `--` to ensure that even a `remote_dir` value that starts with dashes is parsed as a positional argument by `ls`</sub>

Comment: Correction: It doesn't work for inputs containing `\0` characters.

Comment: @melpomene, those aren't "possible" values in the first place, since NULs can't be included in command lines (argument lists being arrays of NUL-terminated C strings at the operating system level).

Comment: This command is much more complex though to wrap a head around than the original one, what "printf -v remote_cmd" here does?

Comment: I am referring to @ARGV

Comment: @Igor, `printf -v` is a more efficient equivalent to for `remote_cmd=$(printf ...)`. The important thing is that we're using the `%q` format string to escape arbitrary content, so it generates a command line that escapes quotes, hidden characters, Unicode characters, and whatever else you run into into a format where it evaluates back to itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know those characters cannot be passed at all, but just ignoring the issue leads to implicit truncation, which may or may not have security implications. String::ShellQuote checks for `\0` characters and throws an exception if they're found.

Comment: @Igor, ...to speak a little bit to why that's important, think about what would happen if someone asked your script to get a listing of the directory with the literal name `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` -- the substring on the left gets expanded unquoted or in double quotes, and the one on the right gets expanded in single quotes, so you can't pass that string *at all* if you don't have some kind of context-aware escaping.

Comment: @melpomene, I definitely won't argue against the statement that using `String::ShellQuote` is the better solution.

Comment: Heck, if it weren't for `\0`, `\n`, and empty strings, you could just half-ass it and use [`quotemeta`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/quotemeta). Alas ...

Comment: That part of code doesn't work with user input at all

Comment: Igor, ...with my security hat on, though -- one needs to look back at what input it *does* work with, where that comes from, and whether a user with less privileges than what the script itself has could influence it. I've seen a major data loss incident caused by nothing more than a buffer overflow (in a C library used by a Python script, so the immediate offender was a program written in a "safe" language) dumping garbage into a filename -- values don't need to be intentionally malicious to cause trouble.

Comment: @Igor, ...and that's before considering issues of code reuse. Just as the answers on this question will be read by other people finding them on Google, someone else (or a future version of you) could well be copying/pasting the practices into somewhere they *do* handle user input. Better to code defensively even when you think it doesn't matter, so you don't discover a vulnerability after it unexpectedly does.

Comment: @Igor, ...moreover, once you get accustomed to working with code following defensive idioms, those idioms stop looking strange/weird/verbose and become second nature. (And beyond that, you get a better idea of how your tools actually *work* under the hood when paying attention to the corner cases; ssh has a bunch of unexpected, unwanted behaviors that only make sense once you realize that it's concatenating all the `command...` arguments together into a single string passed to the remote shell as a single argument -- *after* the calling shell discarded any syntactical quotes).

Comment: Yeah, I used `--` pretty obsessively in scripts. The path is probably an absolute path, but hey, the `--` is free. I did resist passing one to `ssh`, though.

Answer (score 5):

[String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::ShellQuote)'s `shell_quote` is useful in building shell commands.

```
my $remote_cmd = shell_quote("ls", "--", $remote_dir);
my $local_cmd = shell_quote("ssh", "-i", "id_pub", $ssh_addr, $remote_cmd);
system($local_cmd);
```

Of course, you can avoid the shell on the local side as follows:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $remote_cmd = shell_quote("ls", "--", $remote_dir);
system("ssh", "-i", "id_pub", $ssh_addr, $remote_cmd);
```

Comment: I'd argue that it's better to avoid the need to shell-quote the local command (when `system` can be used in its multi-argument form to not invoke a local shell at all), but this is absolutely the Right Way to quote the remote command, and preferable to my own answer.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, duh, of course. I was going to include that but forgot. Fixed.

Comment: I'd give you a second +1 if I could. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) take care of everything for you:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($ssh_addr);
$ssh->error and die "unable to connect to remote host: " . $ssh->error;
if ($ssh->test('test', '-d', $remote_dir)) {
   # do something here!
}
```

Oh, it seems you are on a Windows machine! You can use [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Any) there in a similar fashion.